# os x custom dictionary or custom lookup function

Tags: dictionary, osx-lion, translation, osx-mountain-lion, gestures

In Lion and Mountain Lion you can double-tap-3-fingers to look up word from dictionary. This gesture is so quick, clean and nice way to search for words, but it doens't support custom translations.

Eg. it supports japanese-english translation, but I would need finnish-english translation. Is there a way to add such dictionary. Or write custom function to lookup. Function could also use google translation api, but I don't know how to implement it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm also looking into this. I think it's theoretically possible to create a new OSX dictionary that calls Google Translate, but I'm not sure if anyone's done it.

[Here's](http://nagpals.com/posts/mac-dictionaries/) some info on creating dictionaries, and [here's](https://github.com/mofus/Alfred-Google-Translate) an Alfred plugin (plus shell script) that connects to Google Translate. I'll see what I can do with them.

Answer (score 0):

Download the dictonary you want: [finnish-english](http://clasquin-johnson.co.za/michel/mac-os-x-dictionaries/scandinavian-languages/finnish.html)

To Install:

1. Unzip the file you downloaded. You will find that it contains a single file with the .dictionary extension. In typical Apple style, this is really a directory in disguise. Don't worry about it.
2. To install on your Mac, copy the .dictionary file to /Library/Dictionaries. You may need to supply an administrator password to do this.
3. If Dictionary.app is running, close it down and restart it.
4. Go into Dictionary.app's Preferences and make sure your new dictionary is checked.

More dictonaries: [here](http://clasquin-johnson.co.za/michel/mac-os-x-dictionaries/index.html)

Want more? Downlaod [DictUnifier](https://code.google.com/p/mac-dictionary-kit/) and convert [startDicts](http://abloz.com/huzheng/stardict-dic/) to Dictonary.app format. DictUnifiert automatically loads the dictionary to Dictonary.app

Enjoy!!!